# 'inline' for __global__ functions to avoid multiple definition error

Tags: c++, cuda, linker

I have a CUDA template library, in which one function is actually *not* a template, but *is* defined within a `.cuh` header. (`vector_add_kernel` in `kernel.cuh` below.)

If multiple `.cu` files include `kernel.cuh` and call `vector_add[_kernel]`, it will result in multiple definition errors at link-time. In C++, one can use the `inline` qualifier to avoid such errors.

However, `inline __global__ ...` - while **preventing the multiple definition errors** on my system - results in a warning that the `inline` qualifier has been ignored.

**Q:** Is there a better way to avoid the multiple definition error, or a way to suppress this warning only for this function? And is `inline __global__` even safe, or might other host compilers *truly* ignore it?

I could simply move the `vector_add_kernel` to a separate `.cu` file, but it would be the *only* non-header file. I could also template `vector_add_kernel`, but in my library that makes little sense.

A (not-so-minimal, sorry) working example (tested with CUDA 7.0, gcc 4.7.2 on Debian) is below.

To clarify, `main.cu` is some user's code; `lib.cu` is some external library *not belonging to me*; and `kernel.cuh` is part of my template library. So, both the external `lib` and the user's `main` are using my template library, `kernel.cuh` - but separately.

`main.cu`:

```
#include "lib.hpp"
#include "kernel.cuh"

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    const size_t N = 1u << 7;

    float* a = (float*) malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    float* b = (float*) malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    float* c = (float*) malloc(N * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        a[i] = b[i] = 2.0f * i;
    }

    lib_vector_add(a, b, c, N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (c[i] != 2.0f * i + 2.0f * i)
            std::cout << "Error, lib, element " << i << std::endl;
    }

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_a(a, a + N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_b(b, b + N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_c(N);

    vector_add(d_a, d_b, d_c);
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_c = d_c;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (h_c[i] != 2.0f * i + 2.0f * i)
            std::cout << "Error, element " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`lib.cu`,

```
#include <kernel.cuh>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

void lib_vector_add(float* a, float* b, float* c, size_t N)
{
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_a(a, a + N);
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_b(b, b + N);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_a = h_a;
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_b = h_b;
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_c(N);

    vector_add(d_a, d_b, d_c);

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_c = d_c;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        c[i] = h_c[i];
    }
}
```

`lib.hpp`,

```
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>

void lib_vector_add(float*, float*, float*, size_t);
```

`kernel.cuh` - this form results in a linker error. Uncomment the first `inline` to get a working code.

```
#pragma once

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cstddef>

// inline keyword avoids multiple definition errors, but produces warnings.
// UNCOMMENT TO GET A WORKING EXECUTABLE.
// inline
__global__ void vector_add_kernel(
    const float *const a,
    const float *const b,
    float *const c,
    const size_t N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    while (tid < N)
    {
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

// inline produces no warnings.
inline
void vector_add(
    const thrust::device_vector<float>& d_a,
    const thrust::device_vector<float>& d_b,
    thrust::device_vector<float>& d_c)
{
    const float *const a_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_a.data());
    const float *const b_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_b.data());
    float *const c_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_c.data());

    const size_t N = d_a.size();

    dim3 block(128);
    dim3 grid((N + 127) / 128);

    vector_add_kernel<<<grid, block>>>(a_ptr, b_ptr, c_ptr, N);
}
```

`Makefile`

```
OBJS = main.o lib.o
DEPS = kernel.cuh
CU_ARCH = -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20

all: app

app: $(OBJS)
    nvcc $(CU_ARCH) $(OBJS) -o app

%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
    nvcc $(CU_ARCH) -dc -I./ $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm *.o
```

Comment: The better way is to get function definitions out of header files.  That is general advice, not unique to CUDA.  You've already got `lib.cu`, why not put it in there?

Comment: Because, in reality, only `kernel.cuh` is 'my' code. `lib.cu` is some external library, which uses my `kernel.cuh`, and `main.cu` is some unknown user's code, who is using both my `kernel.cuh` and the external `lib`.

Comment: Maybe using `#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__` around your kernel definition would help? That way it will only get compiled when processed by nvcc.

Comment: @void_ptr that is not valid usage of `__CUDA_ARCH__`

Comment: What might work (aside from the decent solutions in the answer below) is to wrap the function definition in a `#ifdef FOO ... #endif` in `kernel.cuh`, then document it so the user (the person who writes `main.cu`) does `#define FOO` in `main.cu` before doing `#include kernel.cuh`. Then `FOO` won't have been defined in `lib.cu` so the function won't be defined twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep your current code organisation, you have a very simple solution which is to declare your kernel `static` (in place of your `inline` keyword). This will prevent the linker from complaining, but will however generate as many different versions of the kernel as there will be of compilation units (object files) where the `kernel.cuh` will have been included.

Another solution would be to *templatise* your kernel. I know you already dismissed this possibility, but you should reconsider it, since your kernel is a natural template for the `float` type of the input parameters...